# Google Place Api Return UNKNOWN ERROR - Android

Tags: android, google-places-api

We are getting error (UNKNOWN ERROR) when call the google place API for some inputs .

The following requests are now returning UNKNOWN ERROR every time.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?components=country:USA&types=geocode&language=en_US&language=en_fr&types=(cities)&input=27,U&key=YOUR_API_KEY

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?components=country:USA&types=geocode&language=en_US&language=en_fr&types=(cities)&input=US&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Comment: replace your 'YOUR_API_KEY' with your key

Comment: Couldn't reproduce this, but  UNKNOWN ERROR means that error happens on Google backend server, so you should reach out to Google maps support via https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support.